# Locust tool Statistics data is not displayed when running selenium code with locust

Tags: selenium-webdriver, locust

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfKYZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPwi7.png)

Please find the code and statistics image . Locust tool Statistics data is not displayed when running selenium code with locust.

The script is getting run successfully but data not populated in the locust web UI

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is covered by both the Locust docs:

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html

and the Locust FAQ:

https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#locust-web-ui-doesnt-show-my-tasks-running-says-0-rps

> **Locust web UI doesn't show my tasks running, says 0 RPS**
>
> Locust only knows what you're doing when you tell it. There are Event Hooks that you use to tell Locust what's going on in your code. If you use Locust's HttpUser and then use self.client to make http calls, the proper events are normally fired for you automatically, making less work for you unless you want to override the default events.
>
> If you use the plain User or use HttpUser and you're not using self.client to make http calls, Locust will not fire events for you. You will have to fire events yourself. See the Locust docs for examples.